# Fibonacci Numbers using ARM assembly code

Tags: assembly, arm, sum, fibonacci

so I am trying to write a code were I accomplish the following two goals:

Starting at 1, print all the even Fibonacci numbers up to 10946 (inclusive)

Print a sum of all the numbers you printed.

must use a loop

must use a conditional branch for testing even/odd

first things first i have this code i used before to print out all the numbers from 1 to 1000 inclusive and now i want to tweak it in order to satisfy the above goals but i have no idea how to change the size from 1000 to 10946 i keep getting the error: Value 10946 cannot be represented in operand2 format if i can get some help with this im pretty sure i can figure out the rest here is the code i have so far:

```
 .equ SWI_PrStr, 0x69 
    .equ SWI_PrInt,0x6b 
    .equ Stdout, 1 
    .equ SWI_Exit, 0x11 
    .global _start
    .text
    _start:


    MOV R4, #1 @start at this register

    LOOP:
    CMP R4, #10946 @going to check numbers to 10946

    BGE After: 
    MOV R0, #Stdout 
    MOV R1, R4
    SWI SWI_PrInt @Print out all the numbers
    LDR R1, =NL 
    SWI SWI_PrStr
    ADD R4, R4, #2 
    B LOOP

        After:
        SWI SWI_Exit
    .data
    NL: .asciz"\n"
```

so now that i believe i figure out the first part i got this:

```
.equ SWI_PrStr, 0x69 
.equ SWI_PrInt,0x6b 
.equ Stdout, 1 
.equ SWI_Exit, 0x11 
.global _start
.text
_start:

LDR R1,=1 @start at 1
LDR R4, =10946 @going to check numbers to 10946

LOOP: 
MOV R0, #Stdout 
MOV R1, R4
SWI SWI_PrInt @Print out all the numbers
LDR R1, =NL 
SWI SWI_PrStr
ADD R4, R4, #2 
B LOOP

    After:
    SWI SWI_Exit
.data
NL: .asciz"\n"
```

everything load except i get this infinite loop now and I'm trying to figure out how to only print out the even numbers and get the sum of all those even numbers

Comment: ARM instructions can't encode arbitrarily large immediates. Load 10946 into a register using `LDR =` and then use that register wherever you would use the value 10946.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Michael's comment. Immediate values in ARM data processing instructions may be any positive integer with a 32 bit binary representation whose 1s fit into a 2 bit aligned 8 bit block (which may wrap around at bit 0).

Some examples

```
0b00000000111111110000000000000000 ; valid
0b10010000000000000000000000000011 ; valid
0b00000000000000000000001111101000 ; (1000 in decimal) valid
0b00000000000000000010101011000010 ; (10946) invalid
```

Comment: ok so i did the ldr now how would i want to print out all the even numbers from 1 to 10946